# Автоматическое скрытие уведомлений jQuery Noty

Tags: jquery

Сегодня увидел эту библиотеку. Подскажите, кто нибудь ей пользовался?

http://ned.im/noty/#/about

Все подключил все работает как надо, но меня интересует, есть ли у этой библиотеки что бы уведомления закрывались автоматически спустя 5 секнуд, а то по умолчанию надо на них ткнуть что бы они закрылись

Comment: А вы документацию к этой библиотеке вообще читали?

Comment: да читал, не нашел, нашел что бы убивал текущее уведомление и ставил новое

Answer (score 2):

При создании уведомления можно указать волшебную опцию `timeout`, которая и отвечает за автоматическое сокрытие уведомления:

```
noty({
    text: 'test message',
    timeout: 5000 // Уведомление будет скрыто через 5000 мс (5 секунд)
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vhdo7t6n/) с работающим примером.